# how to send local variable to remote server via ssh

Tags: javascript, ssh

So I'm using simple-ssh to work with my remote server on my meteor.js project.
Is there any way I can send local variable to server? Maybe something like

```
name = "dir";

ssh
.exec( 'mkdir' + name , {
    out: console.log.bind(console)
})
```

Comment: would it make you happy to be able to execute a script sitting on your local machine on your remote server ? ... this is very easy using a bash script and command line ssh commands ... I can post a snippet if you like ?

Comment: Well, it's just an example. I don't need to create dir remotely, you know.
Sorry, if I got you wrong @ScottStensland

Comment: @ScottStensland
Actually, I need to pass some stream adresses, which are inputed by user of my project

Comment: @ScottStensland
I will be glad If you post a snippet of what you meant

Comment: I think: `'mkdir' + name` will resolv in `'mkdir/path' (without separation)!... Are you speaking about  ***node.js*** ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find a way -

```
var name = "name1";

ssh
.exec('mkdir ' + name + ' , {
out: console.log.bind(console) 
})
```

This worked for me just fine

Answer (score 0):

save this on your local machine as file script.sh ... it uses ssh to execute the inline bash script on remote host

```
#!/bin/bash

echo REMOTE_IP $REMOTE_IP

# ... 

IFS='' read -r -d '' SSH_COMMAND_01 <<'EOT'

# ... top of inline bash script

echo "These commands will be run on remote host REMOTE_IP
echo "They are executed by: $( whoami )"

set -o errexit

echo put your commands here
echo can put your data inline here to get dealt with on remote box
echo some-local-data > /remoteuser/data_remotefile
echo now remote host has file containing data populated locally

# ... bottom of inline bash script

EOT

echo
echo now that we have defined the SSH_COMMAND_01 now execute it using ssh
echo

ssh remoteuser@${REMOTE_IP} "${SSH_COMMAND_01}"
```

once you have created the ssh key pair and put the public key file on your remote host and jacked up your local environment with your ssh then you are ready to execute above file locally which will jump to remote host and execute the lines in between the start EOT and end EOT

in your local terminal populate this environment variable with the domain name or internet address of your remote server

```
export REMOTE_IP=123.45.678.019  # this defines remote box 

chmod +x script.sh  # make it executable

script.sh   # launch it on your local box
```

separate from above script is the following which can be use to securely copy file(s) from box A to box B

```
#!/bin/bash

echo REMOTE_IP $REMOTE_IP

echo
echo now copy files from local to remote host
echo

sftp remoteuser@${REMOTE_IP} << STENSEOF
  put ${localA_datafile1}             /remoteuser/remoteB_datafile1
  put ${localA_datafile2}             /remoteuser/remoteB_datafile2
STENSEOF
```

Answer (score 0):

By Default OpenSSH Export every variable with LC_ in the name,
create something like this `export LC_FRUIT="banana"` Then ssh user@server, and print this variable, `echo $LC_FRUIT`